# Best instance type for OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I would like to use OrientDb in AWS and I haven't found any suggestions for which kind of instance type I should use. It is better to use an M instance, which has more Memory, or a C instance, which has more CPU Power?

Comment: You should choose the instance according to your needs. Only you know the design of your future DB/infrastructure... its size and usage...

Comment: I just like to know a suggestion from people who using OrientDb in production.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to choose, for most applications, especially stock OrientDB, I'd choose an M instance.  Lack of memory and poor I/O tend to affect OrientDB more than the speed and number of CPUs.

-Colin